# Unable to properly handle errors

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I have found the reason why my application isn't behaving the way I would like it to but I don't know how to resolve the issue. To summarise, my application has a custom error handler which gets invoked if there is an error. The error handler sends `json` messages. But in one application startup error scenario (`Future` fails), I want to `Redirect` the user to homepage instead of sending a `json` message.but it doesn't happen because the custom error handler sends `json` message before I can send a `Redirect` from `Future`'s `recover`.

One feature of the application is signup verification. The user clicks on a `url` which has a token. When the `url` is clicked, `verifyUser` `Action` is called. It does some checks (using database queries using `Future`s) and depending on the success or failure, it sends `Redirect` with `signup=success` or `signup=error` attribute (not failure here is decided based on whether something exists in the database or not). However, if the `Future` fails (I queried a wrong field which is not part of database's schema), I want to `Redirect` again but it doesn't work as the custom error handler gets invoked before `recover`. How could I make my application Redirect?

```
val result:Future[Result] = for{tokenOption:Option[UserToken] <- userTokenRepo.findOne(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))  //generator 1 - get token from database
                                    userOption:Option[User] <- if (tokenOption.isDefined) userRepo.findOne(tokenOption.get.userKeys) else Future.successful(None) //generator2. found token, look for corresponding user to which the token belongs
                                    modifiedUser:Option[User] <- if (userOption.isDefined) confirmSignupforUser(userOption.get) else Future.successful(None) //generator 3. found user and token. Update profile
                                    deletedToken:Option[UserTokenKey] <- if(modifiedUser.isDefined) userTokenRepo.delete(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token))) else Future.successful(None)
       }
         yield { //check if we have user and token and modified user here. If any is missing, return error else success
           println("db query results tokenOption: "+tokenOption+", userOption: "+userOption+" : modifiedUserOption: "+modifiedUser+", deletedToken: "+deletedToken)
           if(tokenOption.isDefined && userOption.isDefined && modifiedUser.isDefined && deletedToken.isDefined)
              Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=success")//TODOM - pick from config
           else
             /*TODOM - when redirecting with error, can provide additional info why sign up failed*/
             if(tokenOption.isEmpty)
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
           else if(userOption.isEmpty)
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
           else if(modifiedUser.isEmpty)
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
           else //this shouldn't happen. Unexpected
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
         }
       result.recover { case x => {
         println("Future failed in validateUserSession. Recovering. Returning Internal Server Error" + x)
//before this Redirect, the custom error handler sends json response

         Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
        }
       }
```

Custom error handler

```
class CustomHttpErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {

    def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
      println("client error: request "+request+", statusCode: "+statusCode+", message:"+message)
      Future.successful(
        Status(statusCode)(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(message)))
      )
    }

    def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable) = {
      println("server error: request: "+request+", exception: "+exception.getMessage)
      Future.successful(
        InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(exception.getMessage)))
      )
    }

}
```

I am able to verify the isse as I see two debugs (one from custom error handler and other from recover)

`server error: request: GET /ws/users/signup/312c9eaf-f27b-43c7-8dac-445a628c3be8, exception: bucket_id is not a column defined in this metadata`

`Future failed in validateUserSession. Recovering. Returning Internal Server Errorjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bucket_id is not a column defined in this metadata`

I could try to check based on the exception received in custom error handler but I think it is too generic and might not be a good design approach.

Comment: In the singup error case you are doing redirect don't you think you should throw your custom exception with the message?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the error is happening before the `Future` is created so the code is throwing an exception that is handled by the default handler rather than being caught by the `Future`.

Specifically, the expression

```
userTokenRepo.findOne(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))
```

is evaluated in the current thread, so any exception in this code will not be caught and will invoke the default error handler.

The solution is to compute this in a `Try` and process the error immediately if there is one.

This is what it might look like:

```
for {
  tokenKey <- Future.fromTry(Try(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token))))
  tokenOption <- userTokenRepo.findOne(tokenKey)
  userOption <- tokenOption.fold(Future.successful)(userRepo.findOne(_.userKeys)) //generator2. found token, look for corresponding user to which the token belongs
  modifiedUser <- userOption.fold(Future.successful)(confirmSignupforUser) //generator 3. found user and token. Update profile
  ...
```

Any exception in this code will result in a failed `Future` which your `recover` code will handle.

Comment: If `findOne` returns Future, why would its execution be happen in current thread? If you meant that `UUID.fromString(token)` might be throwing error then I know that isn't the case. The error happens in `findOne` which runs the code inside a `Future`.

Comment: @ManuChadha `findOne` *returns* a `Future` but it *runs* in the current thread.  There will be some code that runs in this function before it creates the `Future`, and that code will run in the current thread.

Comment: @ManuChadha Also, if you knew that the error was in `findOne` then it would have been helpful to mention it, and to prune down your question to the minimal code that shows the problem.

Comment: sorry about not mentioning that Tim. The definition of `findOne` is `def findone = Future{...}`. So there is no code which runs in current context and the exception is coming from the code (a Cassandra database query) inside `Future{....}`. Cassandra's driver is throwing the exception. AFAIK, if a Future throws exception, it fails and the `recover` should be called. I expected that `recover` is being executed and it handles all cases (`case x`) without further throwing any exception, my custom error handler shouldn't be executed. But both are being executed!!